If $Y$ is a subspace of $X$ then is it true that for every $f\in X^*$, $f|_{Y}\in Y^*$?
Let $(Y, \|.\|)$ be a subspace of $(X, \|.\|)$. $X^*$ refers the topological dual of $X$. Then I have two questions:

Is it true that for every $f\in X^*$, $f|_{Y}\in Y^*$ ?
Does there always exists a a norm preserving extension $\widetilde{f}\in X^*$ of $f\in Y^*$ for every $f$ ?

My attempt to 1. :

$Y\subseteq X \Longleftrightarrow B_Y\subseteq B_X \overset{?}{\Longleftrightarrow} f\in X^*\implies f|_{Y}\in Y^*$.

Am I rightfully attempted? Is the step indicating the question mark right?
My attempt to 2. :
It is the Hahn-Banach extension theorem. Am I right?
Please check my attempts, if found wrong then please help me by providing a right answer to the questions. Any help is appreciated. Thank you in advance.

For 2., yes this is simply the Hahn-Banach extension theorem.
I think you're overcomplicating it for 1.: you just want to look at it using the definition.
You have that $|f(x)| \leq \|f\|_{X^*} \|x\|$ for all $x \in X$, and you want to show that there exists $C \geq 0$ such that $|f(y)| \leq C \|y\|$ for all $y \in Y$.
It's then obvious that you can pick $C = \|f\|_{X^*}$, so that $f$ is linear and bounded on $Y$ with $\|f\|_{Y^*} \leq \|f\|_{X^*}$.
I think the issue I have with your attempt is that it's not clear why the earlier equivalence $B_Y \subset B_X \Leftrightarrow B_{X^*} \subset B_{Y^*}$ is true if you haven't proven the result you are trying to prove, so it sort of becomes a circular argument?

Thank you for your easy solution. In my attempt 1. actually I wanted to see that opposite implications too, i.e., if for every $f\in X^$, $f|_{Y}\in Y^$ then is it true that $Y\subseteq X$? I hope according to your answer it is true. Am I right?

It is easy to see that $B_Y\subseteq B_X\implies B_{X^}\subseteq B_{Y^}$.  For the opposite direction I made a circular argument. You are right. I have edited that part. Now, I think it is ok.

@Tuh I believe I see somewhat what you're trying to investigate, a separate question could probably be made out of this, however you'll have to formalise things a bit more: I'm assuming the setup is that $X$ and $Y$ live in a bigger space $Z$, so that we can make sense of $f|_{X \cap Y}$ for $f \in X^*$ without necessarily having $X \subset Y$ or $Y \subset X$?

Yes, that can also serve my purpose. And it is more general than my query.
